# bootstrap modal event controlling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a form with two 'pages' using bootstrap modal,
when the user clicks "next" it suppose to hide the modal, load new content and show it again. 
but when I close the modal with .modal("hide"), it doesn't close the modal but also shows another modal and make the screen even darker.
also when I click the close button that bootstrap gives us, it shows two modals and a second later hides them, and the second time i click to open the modal i have 3 modals!
whenever i click any button in the modal it adds another modal to the page.
what can i do??
here is some code, the simplest functions that still cause that problem.

```
function additionFormValidate() {
    if ($('#form-modal').is(':visible')) {
        secondPage();
    } else {
        console.log("modal didnt open");
    }
}

function secondPage() {
    $("#form-modal").modal("hide");
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal fade" id="form-modal" onclick="openModal()" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content"></div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="additionFormValidate()">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

does anyone familiar with this?

Comment: Can you provide your html too?

Comment: Can you provide the JS for openModal()?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need `setTimeout()` to prevent javascript to working too fast.

demo: http://jsbin.com/remevolemi/3/edit?html,output

```
$('.btn1').click(function(){
      $('#modal1').find('.modal-body').text('first content');
      $('#modal1').modal('show');
    });

    $('.btn-next').click(function(){
      $("#modal1").modal('hide'); //hide modal
      setTimeout(function(){
        $("#modal1").find('.modal-body').text('second content'); //change modal content
        $('#modal1').modal('show');//show modal again
      }, 500); //wait 0.5 sec

    });
```

here some example for another case: http://jsbin.com/edit?html,output

Comment: you are better off using the hidden.bs.modal event rather than a timeout.

Comment: problem solved! , the html was divided because of the content loading so the function-call was written twice by mistake which made the modal appear too many times . Thank you anyway

Comment: @Nattrass nice. i just know this. you are awesome mannn... thanks